# Any way to hide the "Advanced Reboot" option in Power menu in AospExtended?

Tags: 8.1-oreo, aosp, power-options

An **Advanced Reboot** option appears in the **Power Menu**(which appears on holding the Power button) which gives me a bad feeling since my phone ends up in a lot of hands. Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Settings > Developer Options > Toggle Advanced Reboot Menu

Comment: I searched there first as well. It isn't there.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your phone "ends up in a lot of hands", the option can also be re-enabled by anyone who wants to use it.

Comment: AOSP extended is a custom rom, I think you should ask these things in the ROM thread or somewhere else

Comment: @MártonMolnár The hands in which it ends up aren't experienced. Otherwise, I wouldn't have bothered. :)

Answer (score 2):

I asked this on their [Telegram group](https://t.me/aospextendedgroup)(which is great):

Extensions -> Systems -> Buttons -> Power Menu -> Advanced Reboot